# Spacing Bug with HTML Element <select> / <option> in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, dropdown, spacing

I created a Dropdown with

```css
.some_class {
  border: 1px solid #7f9db9;
}
```

```html
<select id="some_id" class="some_class" size="1">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">User1</option>
  <option value="2">User2</option>
  <option value="3">User3</option>
</select>
```

and it is working fine in the most cases. The Problem is, that sometimes huge empty spaces appear between the listed elements in the dropdown when using Chrome. It looks like something increased the line distance between the element or something like that.
The weird thing is that this bug does not appear in every chrome if i test it with different users / at different computers.
Is it possible that there are any settings in the browser which cause this problem?

Comment: Have you [normalized your CSS](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)?

Comment: Is this your whole code? Or are there other factors that could influence this issue? Also, I second @Martin his question.

Comment: Have you tested that web page using incognito mode on the same computers?

Comment: @Martin: no i haven't normalized my css yet, i'm gonna check that out first.

Comment: @Rubenxfd: no that's not the whole code, thats just a part of a web application nested in  divs and forms.

Comment: Try to find out issue using inspect element, to make overwrite property use !important keyword at the end of property.

Comment: @Martin: normalizing the css did not solve the problem.

Comment: @Karolis: i just tested the same page using incognito mode and the problem does also appear in icognito mode.

Comment: Well, it may also be a sort of problem related to a browser window size. Could it be that this is only an issue on lower resolution computers (or vice versa)? For testing purposes, you may try resizing the browser window.

Comment: I had the same kind of problem in Chrome, I got black borders added(top/left) on expanding select element and it was a screen resolution problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra spacing is a "feature" introduced in Chrome 59.  If it thinks you have a touch device, it makes the options taller.  Currently the only way to disable this feature is to disable all touch devices.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=739196&q=dropdown&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified